# Как передать параметр на поточный элемент списка?

Tags: jquery, javascript

есть объект

```
var object = function(){
  var self = this;
  this.ul = $("ul");
  this.li = document.createElement("li");
  $(this.ul).append(this.li);
  $(this.li).click(function(th){
    th.className = 'green';
  });

};

var a = new object();
```

как вместо th передать параметр на поточный элемент списка??

Comment: Какая ужасная лапша кода

Подключить jquery и пользоваться document.createElement("li") th.className = 'green' - глупо

Пользуйтесь $('<li></li>') и $(th).addClass('green')

Comment: Вместе с кодом javascript добавьте кусок HTML, который должен с ним работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и хочется взять указку и по пальцам ...

```
var object = function(){
    this.$ul = $("ul");
    this.$li = $('<li>').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('green');
    });

    $(this.$ul).append(this.$li);
};
```

Просто пишем правильно и сразу решаются все проблемы)

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul><li>один</li><li>два</li><li>три</li></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
// при клике по списке ul, А ИМЕННО по одному из элементов списка li
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){
    // this - это элемент на котором произошло событие
    var li = $(this);
    li.addClass('green');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял что вы хотите. Но, насколько я знаю, функция jquery click передает в callback (в функцию, которая будет вызвана при клике) объект события. И из этого объекта можно достать поточный элемент списка:

```
$(this.li).click(function(event){
    // this.li === event.currentTarget;

});
```

Или, я могу заблуждаться, эта callback функция будет вызвана в контексте (this) this.li. То есть вам может подойти просто:

```
$(this.li).click(function(event){
    // this === $(li);
});
```

Comment: th.className = 'green';   - неправильный подход

Comment: Согласен, уже исправил.